Extracting specific columns to new DataFrame as a copy based on certain conditional values
This is a snippet of a dataframe I am working with, including angles for specific joints and their values.
mydf = pd.DataFrame({'LHip' : [4,5,6,6,7], 'LKnee' : [10,20,8,8], 'RHip' : [100,50,20,80], 'RKnee' : [-30,-50,-60,-70]})

My actual dataframe holds 54 variables with 27 joint angles, but each having a value for Left (L) and Right (R).
I would like to split this dataframe into 2 new dataframes, 1 holding all values for the Left side and 1 holding all values for the Right side.
From this question:
Extracting specific selected columns to new DataFrame as a copy
I know that I can use
new = old[['A', 'C', 'D']].copy()

To make the copy dataframe, but I would like to build in the conditional value that 'L' and 'R' columns are selected automatically.
Any help on how to approach this would be vermy much appreciated.

You can use pandas.DataFrame.filter with a regex pattern:
df_L = mydf.filter(regex="^L")
df_R = mydf.filter(regex="^R")

   LHip  LKnee
0     4     10
1     5     20
2     6      8
3     6      8
   RHip  RKnee
0   100    -30
1    50    -50
2    20    -60
3    80    -70

